# Use radio button to activate a calculation in Acrobat form

Tags: pdf, radio-button, acrobat

I would like a radio button to activate a calculation in my Acrobat form. If the user clicks on option 3 (from a total of 3 options), the form should calculate the quantity showing in a field ("total number of items ordered") with a fixed number (4.00) and show the result in the "overseas shipping fee" field. If they choose one of the other 2 radio button options, the calculation will not be made.
I appreciate the help...
Ric

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to attach the calculation to the radio button fields; whenever a radio button field (or a check box field) changes, the Forms Calculation Sequence is executed. That means, you can attach the calculation to any field.

In fact, it is considered best practice to attach the whole calculation for a form to a hidden field which itself is not involved in the calculation.

In that calculation script (or calculations function), you would test for the value of your radio button, and if it is the third option (with its particular return value), you do the calculation, otherwise, you don't, and if in the calculation, you set some field values, you'd reset those particular fields.

Comment: I appreciate the information Max. As I am a beginner with Acrobat form creation, I am not sure how to proceed and what script to put in which field. You mentioned that I do not have to attach the calculation to the radio buttons, but I still need to make the click of one radio button activate the associated calculation, I have uploaded my file here (http://www.songstyles.com/railform_15_final_b_ONO.pdf) and explanation of my problem here (http://www.songstyles.com/form_explanation.pdf). If you have a chance to look at them and are able to clarify the solution, I would be grateful!